# Localizing a form in nested namespace suddenly generates runtime exceptions

Tags: .net, visual-c++

Had a form working well until I localized it - then it generated runtime exception and resources were not found.

Namespace is nested one level extra from root.

```
namespace MyApp
{
  namespace NextLevel
  {

    <MyForm class>

  }
}
```

and MyApp also correspond to Assembly name.

Removing the NextLevel so only MyApp::MyForm and it works as before.

Removing localization and it works as well, as nested or not.

If of any importance this is C++/CLI, and a dll assembly.

I tried for the resx files - add the .NextLevel in between for the resources name template, but result is the same.

My core resources are neutral(embedded) and then an English one(that becomes satelite).

Any ideas?

How does resources get named internally for resourcemanager to find them?

Much obliged.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Solved - here is what I did.

In a sideproject I got exactly the same problem/result adding a nested namespace level.
I added the extra level like ".NesxtLevel" into the resx files to make resources names correctly.

I added the renamed resources file in linker input as embedded managed resource.

And that worked - but I felt - why should I have to enter each resources file here manually.

I looked at build log and saw that /out still reference as /ASSEMBLYRESOURCE: the resources file the same as basename for resx file plus rootnamespace, not the logical name with extra namespace in it.

I manually removed the old resources files with the same basename as resx file.

And that solved it. I could remove the embedded resource I added in linker options as well.

Always figured the rebuilding of project also removed old resources files, but obviously not. So it seems that when VS is creating the command line, if a resources file exist with roonamespace+resx-filename as logical name - it picks that one - not the one created by the resources compiler settings.

It's VS 2005, so it's no use talking to MS about it. Just glad it's solved.